# Creating .sql DB schema when installing app and running as regular user

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2008, privileges

I ave an app that executes a .sql file with commands to create and setup a DB in SQL Express 2008.
It installs and executes it with admin privileges, but I'd also like to have regular users execute the app and have access to the DB.
I'm using ordinary setup projects with Visual Studio 2008, NOT ClickOnce.

How could I do that?

EDITED: I run into http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/addselftosqlsysadmin/ which partially solves the problem, but still the admin needs to execute that script with admin privileges so the regular user can be added to SQL Express. Is it possible to do something like this without having to use the admin user?

Comment: Unless your 'ordinary' user has the create database privilege, you are stuffed.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson how can I do that? Maybe that'll resolve the problem

Comment: (GRIN) Well you need to log on as an admin and give them it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run scripts to create and setup the DB only once, when the application is installed. Installers must be run by administrators only. There is a reason for this...
The 'regular user' should be able only to run the application and access the DB.

Comment: yes, that's the thing: I found this link blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/02/23/…, and that script does exactly what I want. The problem is that the admin needs to run the script so the regular user can be added. Would it be possible to do a workaround, so this script is executed whenever the regular user starts the app for the first time? or at least, to do some action that allows the regular user to have access to that DB

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly the steps. Assuming you have created the DB already, you can also create the user and give permissions. Or, you can use SSPI (as MS recommends) and the regular user should be able to access it. From security perspective, it's very important to control who is able to access your resource and how. You should thrive to control access, not allow anybody to gain access by his own will.

Comment: What I finally did was using /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Users" in the package.xml, so we add the users to the Sysadmin accounts in SQL Express 2008.

Comment: You granted SYSADMIN role to all regular users ! This is not a good idea ! If you run the setup as admin, you should have all priviledges needed to grant user permission to your database. If you don't run as admin, I don't think you'll have any permission needed to create DB

Comment: then what could be the solution? I realized that in XP, this is not valid, as the .mdf files will be located in ProgramsFiles in the Administrator folder, to which regular users can't have access..

Comment: As I said, the normal path is to install application as admin (there are tools for automated software deployment) and, as part of setup, grant user permissions. But it would be better if you use a central server for all clients and have DBA grant permissions for each user - you could use Integrated Security.